# @font-face not working

Tags: css, font-face

HI, I am pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong in that @font-face config, because it's not working in any browser, here is my css file:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: BodyFont;
     src: url('../ItcKabMed.eot');
     src: local('ITC Kabel'),
          url('../Kabel_ITC') format('opentype'),
          url('../Kabel_ITC') format('svg');
}
body {
  font-family: 'BodyFont';
  color: #797979;
  background: url("") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #d7d7d7;
  min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Some ideias, why my font is not showing up?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you can see [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/), to achieve crossbrowser success when using `@font-face` we need to use many font formats. So, convert your font to `eot`, `ttf` and `svg` and explicit use this formats:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ITC Kabel';
    src: url('ITCKabel.eot');
    src: local('ITC Kabel'), 
         local('ITCKabel'), 
         url('ITCKabel.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('ITCKabel.svg#font') format('svg'); 
}
```

Comment: right!.. now I realize that I just have the font in PostScript format! and I have to convert it to those others types. I`m trying to use some online converters but none of them are workin! dont know why!

Comment: PostScript isn't a widely used format like TrueType then online tools could had problems interpreting it. Maybe be better to use some Mac program to do it. I'm not a Mac user, then I couldn't test, but [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/) looks very promising. If it don't works too, maybe your font has some problem. Try with another font to see if the problem is with the font itself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you didn't forget the file extensions from your font paths?

Comment: um.... the point is, the file(font) I have it`s without any extension. I`m using mac, and if I go to the properties of the files it`s saying- kind: Font Suitcase